# Unable to retrieve the certificate with codesign after signing the pkg with productsign

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder, codesign, productsign

I am struggling for the past 2 weeks with publishing the .pkg.

If I execute `codesign -dvv app-version.pkg`

I get `app-version.pkg: code object is not signed at all`

Then I want to sign it with `productsign --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: xxx (yyy)" ./app-version.pkg ./app-version-signed.pkg`

The output is:

```
productsign: signing product with identity "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: xxx (yyy)" from keychain /Users/<user>/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
productsign: adding certificate "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority"
productsign: adding certificate "Apple Root CA"
productsign: Wrote signed product archive to ./app-version-signed.pkg
```

When I check my codesign with `codesign -dvv app-version-signed.pkg`, I get the same result.
`app-version-signed.pkg: code object is not signed at all`

---

We are using electron-builder to build the pkg but the pkg is not signed yet. The app is signed with `Developer ID application` and `3rd Party Mac Developer Application`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: use `pkgutil --check-signature` instead of `codesign -dvv`.

Long answer: flat packages use a somewhat different signing format than other things, and you need to use different tools to sign them & check the signatures. Specifically, use `productsign` instead of `codesign` to sign them, and `pkgutil` instead of `codesign` to check the signature.

When you use `codesign -dvv` on a package, it's looking for its format of signature, and indeed there isn't one there.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the explanation. I was getting confused with other forum posts. It indeed says that it is signed with `3rd Party Mac Developer: xxx (yyy)`. But it also says the following: `Status: signed by a developer certificate issued by Apple (Development)`. When I search for that, I find one unsolved SO post. Should it not say something regarding distribution?